# Is it Sparsest or Most Sparse?

Tags: adjectives, superlative-degree

Is the superlative of the adjective *sparse*, *sparsest* or *most sparse*?  Can both be used? If not, then which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

*Sparsest* would be the correct form. Nevertheless, a quick peek in a dictionary could have provided you with this answer.

Comment: Your [link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sparsest) is missing.

Comment: @Bill Franke I did not know that a link was necessary for every answer, whether or not one is requested. As a link has not been requested, I *shan't* be providing one, especially for a question for which the answer is so extremely simple to find.

Comment: I see that I misread your ambiguous answer. I thought that you had intended to provide the OP with a link when you said "**this** answer" instead of "**the** answer". Sorry about that. You **don't** have to provide a link with every answer, you're right.

Comment: Ah. I see now. Thank you for that clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The word *sparsest* is the correct choice of expression. The number of syllable in the adjective (or adverb) determines if the superlative should end with the suffix "*-est*" or begin with the adverb "*most*". When it has only one syllable (e.g. *sparse*), or two but ends with the letter "*y*" (e.g. *happy*), the suffix "-est" should be used to form the superlative (e.g. *sparsest, happiest*), or else we use the adverb "*most*" (e.g. *most peaceful, most horrific*).

> **[most](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/most?q=most)**
>
> forming the superlative of adjectives and adverbs, **especially those of more than one syllable**: *the most important event of my life | he was the most ambitious of all*

Note: there are cases where the rules above do not apply. (e.g. *good & best, bad & worst*)

Answer (score 1):

They're actually both correct depending on context. Google Ngram Viewer shows a substantial number of hits for "[most sparse](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=most%20sparse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)", e.g., "[the AEC algorithm outcome is the distance between points in the most sparse clusters](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22most%20sparse%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en)".

While the normal superlative is "[sparsest](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sparsest)", in a list of superlatives, you will probably want to use parallel structure so that all are in the same form, e.g., "X is the **most interesting, traditional, and sparse** of the options".

"Correct" is often a relative concept, especially with natural language.